# How to post FormData without Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

Is there any way to append `FormData` created through `javascript` to a regular `<form>` POST action?

I have an "old-style" `<form>`, its submitting reloading the entire page, without any fancy `Ajax` gimmicks. What I want is to be able to use a nice file-uploading script, that utilizes drag & drop and image previews, while retaining the old form behaviour.

So far all the scripts served only to create a `FormData` object and append data to it, but I have found no way to add that retrieved information to a classical form `POST` request.

Does anyone know the way to do this? Thank you.

EDIT: Sorry guys, took me a while to extract and test a working code prototype:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form" id="image_form" method="post" action="http://www.mysite.local/upload_image.php">
  <div id="dropbox">Drag your image here</div>

  Or try old-style upload:<br />
  <input type="file" id="upload_input" name="new_image">

  <button id="upload_btn" type="submit">Upload file!</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var form_data = new FormData(document.getElementById('image_form'));
  $('#dropbox').on('drag dragstart dragend dragover dragenter dragleave drop', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // just so that drag&drop works
    e.stopPropagation(); // just so that drag&drop works
  })
  .on('drop', function(e) {
    $.each( e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files, function(i, file) {
      form_data.append("new_image", file);  // appending file to form_data
    });
   // form_data is now Ajax ready, but the form knows nothing about it
   // upon submitting the form, the information won't be a part of $_POST
  });
</script>
```

Comment: @urfusion, _No form_, _No ajax_. Do you have any other solution ?

Comment: With checking the code it is hard to say anything.

Comment: All a form post does is get all "name=" and "value=" attributes and map them. Just create javascript that modifies these attributes!

Comment: Is there a form variable, show us some code?

Comment: Did you find a solution?